# How to move radar chart / spider chart labels in R fmsb for R Shiny so labels don't overlap with plot?

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, axis-labels, radar-chart

I have a shiny app that creates a spider plot using the `fmsb` package based on users input on a short quiz. However, 2 of the labels, overlap with the plot, and I cannot find a way to move them further out.

[image]

I've tried playing with the `paxislabels` argument, but I cannot figure it out and the [help documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/fmsb/man/radarchart.html) or this [great tutorial](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/143-spider-chart-with-saveral-individuals.html) isn't clear on that portion. I want the horizontal labels to be like the vertical ones--outside of the plot.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(fmsb)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(                     selectInput("q1", label = "question 1", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q2", label = "question 2", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q3", label = "question 3", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q4", label = "question 4", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q5", label = "question 5", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q6", label = "question 6", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q7", label = "question 7", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          actionButton("submit", "Submit")),

        mainPanel(
            mainPanel(plotOutput("spider_chart"))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data_scores <- reactive({
        
        #Make tibble of raw data
        raw_data <- tibble(`Variable 1` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q1), as.numeric(input$q2), na.rm = T)),
                              `Variable 2` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q2), as.numeric(input$q3)), na.rm = T),
                              `Variable 3` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q4), as.numeric(input$q5)), na.rm = T),
                              `Variable 4` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q5), as.numeric(input$q6), as.numeric(input$q7)), na.rm = T))
    
        #fbsm needs the first 2 rows to be the max and min values
        min_max <- tibble(`Variable 1` = c(2, 0),
                          `Variable 2` = c(2, 0),
                          `Variable 3` = c(2, 0),
                          `Variable 4` = c(3, 0))
        
        min_max %>%
            full_join(raw_data)
        
    })
    
#This is the section that needs to be updated
    output$spider_chart <- renderPlot({
        req(input$submit)
        
        colors_border=rgb(.5, 0, .5, .9)
        colors_in=rgb(.5, 0, .5, .5)
        
        # plot with default options:
        radarchart(data_scores(), 
                   #custom polygon
                   pcol=  colors_border, pfcol=colors_in , plwd=4 , plty=1,
                   #custom the grid
                   cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey",cglwd=0.8, paxislabels = c(10, 10, 10, 10),
                   #custom labels
                   vlcex= 1.2
        )  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote directly to the creator of fmsb, Minato Nakazawa, and he provided an extremely easy to implement answer. In short, all the labels act like general text strings, so he suggested renaming the variables using the `vlabel` argument within my `radarchart()` call and adding spaces to the two horizontal axis titles, and it worked! Below is what it looks like with adding 10 spaces:

[image]

Here's the full code with the addition:

```
library(shiny)
library(fmsb)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(                     selectInput("q1", label = "question 1", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q2", label = "question 2", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q3", label = "question 3", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q4", label = "question 4", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q5", label = "question 5", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q6", label = "question 6", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          selectInput("q7", label = "question 7", choices = c("", "Yes" = 1, "Somewhat" = .5, "No" = 0)),
                                          actionButton("submit", "Submit")),

        mainPanel(
            mainPanel(plotOutput("spider_chart"))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data_scores <- reactive({
        
        #Make tibble of raw data
        raw_data <- tibble(`Variable 1` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q1), as.numeric(input$q2), na.rm = T)),
                              `Variable 2` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q2), as.numeric(input$q3)), na.rm = T),
                              `Variable 3` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q4), as.numeric(input$q5)), na.rm = T),
                              `Variable 4` = sum(c(as.numeric(input$q5), as.numeric(input$q6), as.numeric(input$q7)), na.rm = T))
    
        #fbsm needs the first 2 rows to be the max and min values
        min_max <- tibble(`Variable 1` = c(2, 0),
                          `Variable 2` = c(2, 0),
                          `Variable 3` = c(2, 0),
                          `Variable 4` = c(3, 0))
        
        min_max %>%
            full_join(raw_data)
        
    })
    
#This is the section that needs to be updated
    output$spider_chart <- renderPlot({
        req(input$submit)
        
        colors_border=rgb(.5, 0, .5, .9)
        colors_in=rgb(.5, 0, .5, .5)
        
        # plot with default options:
        radarchart(data_scores(), 
                   #custom polygon
                   pcol=  colors_border, pfcol=colors_in , plwd=4 , plty=1, vlabels = c("Variable 1", "Variable 2          ", "Variable 3", "          Variable 4"),
                   #custom the grid
                   cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey",cglwd=0.8, paxislabels = c(10, 10, 10, 10),
                   #custom labels
                   vlcex= 1.2
        )  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

A huge thank you to Minato Nakazawa for creating this package and for his prompt reply to my inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that has been written by Minato Nakazawa for `radarchart` function in `fmsb` package source code.
It seems there is no place for pull request of this package, so I post it here.

I have changed a part of this code related to the labels of the variables (commented it in the code block),
by applying appropriate `adj` for labels according to their position relative to `(0,0)` point.

You can copy this function in your code or another file and source it to your main code, and use `radarchart` function as you use from `fmsb` package.

```
radarchart <- function(df, axistype=0, seg=4, pty=16, pcol=1:8, plty=1:6, plwd=1,
                       pdensity=NULL, pangle=45, pfcol=NA, cglty=3, cglwd=1,
                       cglcol="navy", axislabcol="blue", title="", maxmin=TRUE,
                       na.itp=TRUE, centerzero=FALSE, vlabels=NULL, vlcex=NULL,
                       caxislabels=NULL, calcex=NULL,
                       paxislabels=NULL, palcex=NULL, ...) {
  if (!is.data.frame(df)) { cat("The data must be given as dataframe.\n"); return() }
  if ((n <- length(df))<3) { cat("The number of variables must be 3 or more.\n"); return() }
  if (maxmin==FALSE) { # when the dataframe does not include max and min as the top 2 rows.
    dfmax <- apply(df, 2, max)
    dfmin <- apply(df, 2, min)
    df <- rbind(dfmax, dfmin, df)
  }
  plot(c(-1.2, 1.2), c(-1.2, 1.2), type="n", frame.plot=FALSE, axes=FALSE, 
       xlab="", ylab="", main=title, asp=1, ...) # define x-y coordinates without any plot
  theta <- seq(90, 450, length=n+1)*pi/180
  theta <- theta[1:n]
  xx <- cos(theta)
  yy <- sin(theta)
  CGap <- ifelse(centerzero, 0, 1)
  for (i in 0:seg) { # complementary guide lines, dotted navy line by default
    polygon(xx*(i+CGap)/(seg+CGap), yy*(i+CGap)/(seg+CGap), lty=cglty, lwd=cglwd, border=cglcol)
    if (axistype==1|axistype==3) CAXISLABELS <- paste(i/seg*100,"(%)")
    if (axistype==4|axistype==5) CAXISLABELS <- sprintf("%3.2f",i/seg)
    if (!is.null(caxislabels)&(i<length(caxislabels))) CAXISLABELS <- caxislabels[i+1]
    if (axistype==1|axistype==3|axistype==4|axistype==5) {
      if (is.null(calcex)) text(-0.05, (i+CGap)/(seg+CGap), CAXISLABELS, col=axislabcol) else
        text(-0.05, (i+CGap)/(seg+CGap), CAXISLABELS, col=axislabcol, cex=calcex)
    }
  }
  if (centerzero) {
    arrows(0, 0, xx*1, yy*1, lwd=cglwd, lty=cglty, length=0, col=cglcol)
  }
  else {
    arrows(xx/(seg+CGap), yy/(seg+CGap), xx*1, yy*1, lwd=cglwd, lty=cglty, length=0, col=cglcol)
  }
  PAXISLABELS <- df[1,1:n]
  if (!is.null(paxislabels)) PAXISLABELS <- paxislabels
  if (axistype==2|axistype==3|axistype==5) {
    if (is.null(palcex)) text(xx[1:n], yy[1:n], PAXISLABELS, col=axislabcol) else
      text(xx[1:n], yy[1:n], PAXISLABELS, col=axislabcol, cex=palcex)
  }
  VLABELS <- colnames(df)

  if (!is.null(vlabels)) VLABELS <- vlabels
  



  
  ##--------------------------------------------------
  ## Modified by Killbill-(Me)
  ##--------------------------------------------------
  # Main code:
  # if (is.null(vlcex)) text(xx*1.2, yy*1.2, VLABELS) else
  #   text(xx*1.2, yy*1.2, VLABELS, cex=vlcex, adj=adjVec)


  # Modified code:
  # Create a variable that round 'xx' value to 0 and 1 for non zero and 0.5 for 0 values.
  adjVec <- ifelse(round(xx) < 0, 1, ifelse(round(xx) > 0, 0, 0.5))
  
  #apply 'adjVec' variable to "adj" parameters of text.

  for (i in seq_along(xx)){
    if (is.null(vlcex)) text(xx[i]*1.1, yy[i]*1.1, VLABELS[i], adj=adjVec[i]) else
      text(xx[i]*1.1, yy[i]*1.1, VLABELS[i], cex=vlcex, adj=adjVec[i])
  }
  
  ##-------------------------------------------------
  ## End
  ##-------------------------------------------------




  series <- length(df[[1]])
  SX <- series-2
  if (length(pty) < SX) { ptys <- rep(pty, SX) } else { ptys <- pty }
  if (length(pcol) < SX) { pcols <- rep(pcol, SX) } else { pcols <- pcol }
  if (length(plty) < SX) { pltys <- rep(plty, SX) } else { pltys <- plty }
  if (length(plwd) < SX) { plwds <- rep(plwd, SX) } else { plwds <- plwd }
  if (length(pdensity) < SX) { pdensities <- rep(pdensity, SX) } else { pdensities <- pdensity }
  if (length(pangle) < SX) { pangles <- rep(pangle, SX)} else { pangles <- pangle }
  if (length(pfcol) < SX) { pfcols <- rep(pfcol, SX) } else { pfcols <- pfcol }
  for (i in 3:series) {
    xxs <- xx
    yys <- yy
    scale <- CGap/(seg+CGap)+(df[i,]-df[2,])/(df[1,]-df[2,])*seg/(seg+CGap)
    if (sum(!is.na(df[i,]))<3) { cat(sprintf("[DATA NOT ENOUGH] at %d\n%g\n",i,df[i,])) # for too many NA's (1.2.2012)
    } else {
      for (j in 1:n) {
        if (is.na(df[i, j])) { # how to treat NA
          if (na.itp) { # treat NA using interpolation
            left <- ifelse(j>1, j-1, n)
            while (is.na(df[i, left])) {
              left <- ifelse(left>1, left-1, n)
            }
            right <- ifelse(j<n, j+1, 1)
            while (is.na(df[i, right])) {
              right <- ifelse(right<n, right+1, 1)
            }
            xxleft <- xx[left]*CGap/(seg+CGap)+xx[left]*(df[i,left]-df[2,left])/(df[1,left]-df[2,left])*seg/(seg+CGap)
            yyleft <- yy[left]*CGap/(seg+CGap)+yy[left]*(df[i,left]-df[2,left])/(df[1,left]-df[2,left])*seg/(seg+CGap)
            xxright <- xx[right]*CGap/(seg+CGap)+xx[right]*(df[i,right]-df[2,right])/(df[1,right]-df[2,right])*seg/(seg+CGap)
            yyright <- yy[right]*CGap/(seg+CGap)+yy[right]*(df[i,right]-df[2,right])/(df[1,right]-df[2,right])*seg/(seg+CGap)
            if (xxleft > xxright) {
              xxtmp <- xxleft; yytmp <- yyleft;
              xxleft <- xxright; yyleft <- yyright;
              xxright <- xxtmp; yyright <- yytmp;
            }
            xxs[j] <- xx[j]*(yyleft*xxright-yyright*xxleft)/(yy[j]*(xxright-xxleft)-xx[j]*(yyright-yyleft))
            yys[j] <- (yy[j]/xx[j])*xxs[j]
          } else { # treat NA as zero (origin)
            xxs[j] <- 0
            yys[j] <- 0
          }
        }
        else {
          xxs[j] <- xx[j]*CGap/(seg+CGap)+xx[j]*(df[i, j]-df[2, j])/(df[1, j]-df[2, j])*seg/(seg+CGap)
          yys[j] <- yy[j]*CGap/(seg+CGap)+yy[j]*(df[i, j]-df[2, j])/(df[1, j]-df[2, j])*seg/(seg+CGap)
        }
      }
      if (is.null(pdensities)) {
        polygon(xxs, yys, lty=pltys[i-2], lwd=plwds[i-2], border=pcols[i-2], col=pfcols[i-2])
      } else {
        polygon(xxs, yys, lty=pltys[i-2], lwd=plwds[i-2], border=pcols[i-2], 
                density=pdensities[i-2], angle=pangles[i-2], col=pfcols[i-2])
      }
      points(xx*scale, yy*scale, pch=ptys[i-2], col=pcols[i-2])
    }
  }
}
```